# MSBuild Property References

Tags: c#, msbuild, properties

What is the difference between property references such as $(TargetPath) and !(TargetPath) during the MSBuild PreBuildEvent/PostBuildEvent events? I find that they work differently in some situations but I cannot find any documentation on the "!(" form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx
This is the closest I seem to be able to find.

Example:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <CreateProperty Value="NewValue">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
echo $(TargetPath)
echo !(TargetPath)
  </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Will echo the original TargetPath and then echo "NewValue". This however does not work for other properties that I have defined.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting. Can you post a complete proj-file that exhibits this behavior? I have tried to reproduce it by extending a sample "ConsoleApplication1.csproj", but couldn't. The `echo !(TargetPath)` simply prints "!(TargetPath)".

Comment: If something is not documented, you should not use it at all.

Comment: I was pondering and "researching" about this. It looks like the only time "!(" is meaningful to MSBuild, apart from plain text of course, is for use as the "not-operator" in the `Condition` attribute. Example: `Condition="!('$(foo)' == '1')"`. Is it at all possible, that you use some custom tool, preprocessing or alike that interprets the "!(TargetPath)" as something else then plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Having just re-written our build process I can honestly say I have never used ! to reference anything, all I have ever used this character for is to say "NOT" as in a boolean operator.

In fact I cannot find this usage anywhere in the documentation or reproduce the behaviour you are describing.

I strongly suspect this is not valid/supported syntax for referencing anything.